# simple SQL Statement confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, select

apologies I know this must be extremely extremely simple, but I am completely new to this and I am struggling on an simple select SQL Query, I have two tables as seen below.

```
table 1 quiz
QuizID, ....etc.
Int         

table 2 useranswers
UserAnswersID, QuizID, 
Int             Int
```

I simply wish to select the QuizID from the first table using the UserAnswersID from the second table. I tried writing the following with no luck:

```
SELECT A.QuizID
FROM quiz Q, useranswers UA
WHERE UA.UserAnswersID = (**int**)
```

Comment: You are missing a JOIN between the tables. Please read on how to use the `JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Q.QuizID
FROM
    quiz Q,
    useranswers UA
WHERE
    UA.UserAnswersID = Q.QuizID;
```

Or you can use JOIN

```
SELECT 
    Q.QuizID
FROM
    quiz Q
        JOIN
    useranswers UA ON UA.UserAnswersID = Q.QuizID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Q.QuizID
FROM quiz Q inner join useranswers UA
on UA.UserAnswersID = Q.QuizID
```